# Spring Security error 403 when accessing protected endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Ive been following this tutorial on microservice with spring boot and currently doing a microservice on user api microservice. Now, the issue is with spring security as whenever im trying to access my protected endpoint i would always encounter with the error 403 mentioning you dont have the rights to access. I have no idea as to why Im unable to access it as ive registered a user and authenticate the user via login endpoint. Basically the authz authn is trying to implement jwt. Ive tried to narrow down the problem by removing this microservice from the gateway and it seems the problem comes from this microservice itself.
Below I provide the code for the security configuration class as well as authenticationFilter class which is a custom filter chain setup for spring security. Please have a look and help me to resolve this issue. Thanks!

#### Security Configuration:

```
import com.udemyspringboot.photoapp.api.users.service.UsersService;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity {

    private UsersService usersService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    private Environment environment;

    public WebSecurity(UsersService usersService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder, Environment environment) {
        this.usersService = usersService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
        this.environment = environment;
    }
    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

         //Configure AuthenticationManagerBuilder
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);

        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(usersService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);

        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = authenticationManagerBuilder.build();

        // Create AuthenticationFilter
        AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager, usersService, environment);
        authenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl(environment.getProperty("login.url.path"));

        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());

//issue with authz endpoint
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher(HttpMethod.POST, "/users/**")).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll())
                .addFilter(authenticationFilter)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .sessionManagement((session) -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        http.headers((headers) -> headers.frameOptions((frameOptions) -> frameOptions.disable()));
        return http.build();

    }
}
```

#### Authentication Filter class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.udemyspringboot.photoapp.api.users.service.UsersService;
import com.udemyspringboot.photoapp.api.users.shared.UserDto;
import com.udemyspringboot.photoapp.api.users.ui.model.LoginRequestModel;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Base64;

public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private UsersService usersService;
    private Environment environment;

    public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,UsersService usersService, Environment environment) {
        super(authenticationManager);
        this.usersService = usersService;
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        try {

            LoginRequestModel creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(), LoginRequestModel.class);

            return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getEmail(), creds.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>()));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain, Authentication auth)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        String userName = ((User)auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
        UserDto userDetails = usersService.getUserDetailsByEmail(userName);
        String tokenSecret = environment.getProperty("token.secret");
        byte[] secretKeyBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(tokenSecret.getBytes());
        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(secretKeyBytes, SignatureAlgorithm.HS512.getJcaName());

        Instant now = Instant.now();
        String token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(userDetails.getUserId()).setExpiration(Date.from(now.plusMillis(Long.parseLong(environment.getProperty("token.expiration_time"))))).setIssuedAt(Date.from(now)).signWith(secretKey, SignatureAlgorithm.HS512).compact();

        res.addHeader("token", token);
        res.addHeader("userId", userDetails.getUserId());
    }
}
```

#### Controller class (just in case)

```
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.modelmapper.convention.MatchingStrategies;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.udemyspringboot.photoapp.api.users.service.UsersService;
import com.udemyspringboot.photoapp.api.users.shared.UserDto;
import com.udemyspringboot.photoapp.api.users.ui.model.CreateUserRequestModel;
import com.udemyspringboot.photoapp.api.users.ui.model.CreateUserResponseModel;

import jakarta.validation.Valid;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    UsersService usersService;

    @GetMapping("/status/check")
    public String checkServer() {
        return "Working...";
    }


    //this controller will accept the input entered by user and is mapped  into CreateUserRequestModel class first
    //then we convert the CreateUserRequestModel class into userDTO class
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<CreateUserResponseModel> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody CreateUserRequestModel userDetails){
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);

        //map from CreateUserRequestModel to userDto, userDto is what sent to db
        UserDto userDto = modelMapper.map(userDetails, UserDto.class);

        //userDto object is then passed to createUser method in service to encrypt pw and set uid
        UserDto createdUser = usersService.createUser(userDto);
        //now we have a createdUser object, we then want to structure the response to be sent hence we map it again
        CreateUserResponseModel responseModel = modelMapper.map(createdUser, CreateUserResponseModel.class);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(responseModel);
    }

}
```

Comment: the tutorial you are following seems to have no idea how security works. Handing out JWTs to browsers is from a security standpoint not recommended, and this is why there is no such implementation in spring security. Every tutorial out there that does so, is teaching bad practices. If you wish to implement security i recommend reading the spring security docs, and implement cookie based login using FormLogin.

Comment: Well im still new in the webdev world let alone security. But from what ive learned from other sources that jwts supposed to be handed out to client, and the client side are the one responsible in taking care of the jwt, right? the browser job is to just validate the jwt here and there, isnt it?

Comment: Also yes, to be fair i find  that most of the tutorials can be quite confusing when it comes to configuring spring security as different developers use different approach particularly the authentication manager/builder part. Was wondering if there any like "one fit for all" solution when it comes to configuring spring security, i mean it does not have to be a really one fit for all solution but fair enough to identify the standard practice/pattern of configuring spring security.

Comment: stack overflow is not a forum, and this is a comment section so no lengthy discussions. JWTs were made for short requests between micros services inside an internal network. Not sessions, and everyone that uses them for that will have security issues. If you want to learn spring security ignore all tutorials read https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html and https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html and you will understand more than most ppl. Then implement `FormLogin` there is no single answer for security

Comment: understood sir, thank you very much